# Stop jQuery from scrolling when element changes out of the view

Tags: jquery

I have a very long page. At the top I have a banner div with a background-image that changes every 10 seconds through a timer.

When you scroll down to see the content "below the fold", jQuery then scrolls to the top to show the new banner image.

This is very disruptive -how could I stop jQuery from scrolling to the top? Thank you.

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('div#banner').css('background-image', 'url(...)'; }
    // set timeOut again.
, 10000);
```

Comment: You should use `setInterval()` if you want to fire events on a given interval. Also, setting the background image with the `css()` function won't scroll the page, I'm assuming something else must also be executing. Can you post your full code?

Comment: I don't know why it would do that just on a CSS background change. There must be something else going on - what other code do you have on this page?

Comment: Also, does your div really have an ID of div, and not just a tag of div? I guess so, if the image change works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI -As the comments points out, the issue was not caused by the "css" function but by a "fadeOut" "fadeIn" effect. Hope this helps somebody else. Thank you.